# AngularJS from $scope get form controller programmatically

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Is there anyway I could access form controller from scope without knowing what what user define for form name.

Normally, we would access the form controller this way:

```
$form['register_form']
```

However, I am looking for way that can access to the form controller without knowing the form name. Example:

```
$form[$scope.form_name]
```

I assume there's reference to form name or form controller from $scope itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the form using

```
angular.element(el).inheritedData('$formController');
```

This will get a reference to the element's parent form.

I've created a plunker example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/hbuyOIOGsWGaBGNsl97B?p=preview). However, I wouldn't do this within a controller as I have done in the example. I'd put whatever logic you require a parent form for into a directive. Something like this:

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
      return {
        require: '^form',
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope){
           $scope.$watch('form', function(val){
               // some controller logic
           });
        }],
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, frm) {
          scope.form = frm;
          // your other logic
        }
      };
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If form isn't in `$scope`, you can put it there yourself. For example, it's possible with new directive named `form`, since AngularJS allows multiple directives of the same name.

Here's an extremely naive version of it:

```
.directive("form", function () {
  function link (scope, el, attr, ctrl) {
    scope.forms = scope.forms || [];
    if (scope.forms.indexOf(ctrl) === -1) {
      scope.forms.push(ctrl);
    } 
  }
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    link: link,
    require: "form"
  }
})
```

What I've done:

1. Created new directive that will initialize on `form` elements.
2. Required original `form` directive controller.
3. Exposed it through `scope.forms` colletions.

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/nudonige/3/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: Your solution excludes angular's support for nested forms. http://jsbin.com/rahomeve/2/edit

Comment: I didn't claim it does. For nested forms, you'll need similar directive for ngForm.